# MUI DataGrid Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MuiDataGrid')

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, locale

I was trying to change the language of the default parameters of my `DataGrid` MUI parameters and for some reason I'm getting an error when I try to add the `localeText` I'm following the exact instructions from their resource page, [Locale Text](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/localization/#locale-text)

[image]

This is the error it shows:

[image]

This is what I'm doing (just adding relevant code):

```
import { DataGrid, esES} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

<DataGrid 
  localeText={esES.props.MuiDataGrid.localeText}
  rows={estudiantes}
  columns={columns}
  autoPageSize 
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the docs is outdated, if you log the `esES` variable you will know what to put in `localeText`:

```
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  localeText={esES.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
  components={{
    Toolbar: GridToolbar
  }}
/>
```

In v4, `esES.props.MuiDataGrid.localeText` can be used because this is how you override the default props:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  props: {
    MuiDataGrid: {
      localeText: {...},
    },
  },
});
```

In v5, it's `esES.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText` because the default props path is changed to:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiDataGrid: {
      defaultProps: {
        localeText: {...},
      },
    },
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Reference

- https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#theme-structure

Comment: Oh thank you very much it worked

Comment: Thank you so much this is working for me but I wonder why the did  not update the doc?